# What is wrong with this matplotlib code?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot datetime on y axis and time on x-axis using a bar graph. I need to specify the heights in terms of datetime of y-axis and I am not sure how to do that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

# Make a series of events 1 day apart
y = mpl.dates.drange(dt.datetime(2009,10,1), 
                 dt.datetime(2010,1,15), 
                 dt.timedelta(days=1))
# Vary the datetimes so that they occur at random times
# Remember, 1.0 is equivalent to 1 day in this case...
y += np.random.random(x.size)

# We can extract the time by using a modulo 1, and adding an arbitrary base date
times = y % 1 + int(y[0]) # (The int is so the y-axis starts at midnight...)

# I'm just plotting points here, but you could just as easily use a bar.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(times, y, width = 10)

ax.yaxis_date()
fig.autofmt_ydate()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be your y range.
When I do your code I get a plot with the y axis ranging from about 11/Dec/2011 to 21/Dec/2011.

However, you've generated dates ranging from 1/10/2009 to 15/1/2010.

When I adjusted my y limits to take this into account it worked fine. I added this after the `ax.bar`.

```
plt.ylim( (min(y)-1,max(y)+1) )
```

Another reason the output is confusing is that since you've picked a width of 10, the bars are too wide and are actually obscuring each other.

Try use `ax.plot(times,y,'ro')` to see what I mean.

I produced the following plot using `ax.bar(times,y,width=.1,alpha=.2)` and `ax.plot(times,y,'ro')` to show you what I meant about bars overlapping each other:
[image]

And that's with a width of .1 for the bars, so if they had a width of 10 they'd be completely obscuring each other.

Comment: mod date with 1 will give you the individual times

Comment: the problem seems to be the height parameter in bar. i am not sure how you feed datetime for height

Comment: Ahh, I agree. sorry about my first answer: you should have `+= np.random.random(y.size)` instead of `x.size`. At first I didn't notice the error that resulted and so my `y` ended up being a bunch of integers, which of course gives `0` when you do a `% 1` on it. I've updated my answer to what I think the problem might be.

Comment: at least the statement does not throw an error. Did you try what I mentioned in my (updated) answer with the `plt.ylim`?